# Trying to make a bot that automatically press the displayed buttons on the screen from png files

Tags: python, opencv, keyboard, pyautogui

Program doesn't work, don't know what I can do to make it work
I don't even know if I started writing the code right
I expect the program to work correctly
Will automatically press the displayed buttons on the screen from png files
It would be nice if it could be activated by a button, for example (ALT + 2)

```
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Funkcja do wykrywania przycisków na ekranie
def detect_button(button_image):
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 1920, 1080))  # Dostosuj obszar zrzutu ekranu do rozmiaru gry
    screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, button_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    threshold = 0.8  # Ustaw próg dopasowania, możesz dostosować go do swoich potrzeb

    if max_val >= threshold:
        return max_loc
    else:
        return None

# Główna pętla
while True:
    # Wykrywanie i klikanie przycisku "lpm.png"
    lpm_button = cv2.imread("lpm.png")
    lpm_location = detect_button(lpm_button)
    if lpm_location:
        x, y = lpm_location
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        print("Naciśnięto lewy przycisk myszy")

    # Wykrywanie i klikanie przycisku "q.png"
    q_button = cv2.imread("q.png")
    q_location = detect_button(q_button)
    if q_location:
        x, y = q_location
        pyautogui.press('q')
        print("Naciśnięto klawisz 'q'")

    # Wykrywanie i klikanie przycisku "e.png"
    e_button = cv2.imread("e.png")
    e_location = detect_button(e_button)
    if e_location:
        x, y = e_location
        pyautogui.press('e')
        print("Naciśnięto klawisz 'e'")

    time.sleep(1)  # Czekaj 1 sekundę przed kolejnym sprawdzeniem
```